# Count Table Rows then addClass

Tags: jquery, html-table, dom-traversal

I'm trying to addClass to make a link appear when there are 20 table items.

I have more than one table on the page, each one is inside of a div.box

What I want to do is if there are 20 tr rows addClass to make a link visible.  This needs to happen to each individual table, how would I go about setting this up?

So far I've got:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box tr.table-row").length;


    $('a.single-product-link').addClass('visible');
});
```

But I don't know how to do the "if there are 20 tr.table-row addClass" section.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running the same function for every `.box` element, because they have to be handled separately. In the function, the table rows inside the div are counted, and if there is more than 20, a class is added to the link inside the div.

```
$('.box').each(function () {
    var $this=$(this);
    if ($this.find('tr.table-row').length > 20) {
        $this.find('a.single-product-link').addClass('visible');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E45q2/)

---

Another possible variation (using the function parameter for [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), and inside the function finding the closest `.box` and counting its table rows):

```
$('a.single-product-link').addClass(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('.box').find('tr.table-row').length > 20) {
        return 'visible';
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E45q2/1/)

Comment: Awesome thank you, I used the first variation and it worked like a charm.